# xsl stylesheet won't apply

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm pretty new to XML and XSL/T so i don't really know much about it yet.
So i tried to make a tutorial from http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XSLT_Tutorial_-_Basics and at one point i tried making a little xsl stylesheet but it just don't get displayed right. Does someone see where i'm making a mistake?

XLS:

```
<xsl:template match="student">
    <html> 
        <head> 
            <title> <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></title>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lastname">
    <h1 align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/> <xsl:apply-templates/> </h1>
</xsl:template>
```

XML:

```
<student>
    <firstname>Tim</firstname>
    <lastname>Spilka</lastname>
    <nickname>Timi</nickname>
</student>
```

It gets displayed like that in the Browser:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" http-equiv="Content-Type">
            <title>Tim</title>
        </META>
    </head>
</html>
```

The body just doesn't show up

Comment: Which is the HTML result document you expect to create with XSLT from your XML sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="lastname">
    <h1 align="center"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </h1>
</xsl:template>
```

Within a template rule that matches `lastname`, the `lastname` element is the context node (or context item). When you do `select="lastname"`, it means `select="child::lastname"`, that is, select a child of the context node called `lastname`. Your `lastname` element doesn't have any children called `lastname`, so it selects nothing.

You want `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`